# Camel Route not working asynchronously once message is received from topic

Tags: spring, apache-camel

We have camel route which reads from topic and then performs some transformation on message received it.

Given its durable topic only one message is processed at time, until route finishes its work.

To achieve concurrency, added threadpool so once message is received from topic to further work asynchronously, threads are spawning but its sequential one. Like once message is received thread is picked from pool and starts processing until that thread doesn't finish processing next message is not picked up.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:broker="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">



    <bean id="threadPool" class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" factory-method="newFixedThreadPool">       
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="10"/>
    </bean>

    <camel:camelContext id="camel-etl" trace="true"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">


        <route id="topicRoute" errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler" >


            <from uri="{{inbound.topic}}"/>
            <camel:threads executorServiceRef="threadPool">
                <choice>
                    <when>
                        ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                         ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                         ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                          ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                     <when>
                          ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                         ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                          ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                          ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                          ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <when>
                         ...
                        ...
                        <multicast>
                            some loigc ...
                        </multicast>
                        <bean ref="persistData"/>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        ...
                        <bean ref="deadLetterErrorHandler"/>
                    </otherwise>
                </choice>
            </camel:threads>
        </route>



    </camel:camelContext>

    <!-- XSLT config -->

    <bean id="saxonFactory" class="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>

    <!-- custom component beans -->

    <bean id="persistData" class="com.data.PersistBean"/>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn on asyncConsumer on the JMS endpoint. See the docs at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jms/src/main/docs/jms-component.adoc

Comment: thanks Claus anyways, i already added that post which it worked. (y)

Comment: @Claus Ibsen Claus could you please look at my question about the FTP consumer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223264/apache-camel-do-i-need-to-make-my-ftp-consumer-route-transactional/53223925?noredirect=1#comment93337344_53223925